# Visual Studio 2015 : Windows Phone part

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I want to create a new Cross-Platform project using C# in Visual Studio 2015 i get just the Android and iOS parts. So how i can add the Windows Phone part in my project ?

Comment: If you are developing for Windows 10, please use UWP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the [Windows Phone SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=35471). And then you can add a Windows Phone Project to your solution `File > New > Project`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all of the necessary Windows Phone SDK bits installed for the projects to be added. If you can't create a stand-alone Windows Phone 8/8.1 project in Visual Studio, then Xamarin.Forms won't be able to create the necessary projects.

[Windows Phone 8 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

[Windows Phone 8.1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43719)

If you already have these installed, then you can just add the needed projects to the solution, though the Cross-Platform project template should have created them for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Adding a Windows Phone App](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/phone/)

(Follow the link for a properly formatted view of these instructions)

Firstly, if you used the Xamarin.Forms PCL template, update the profile, then follow the instructions below:

1 right-click on solution > Add > New Project... and add a Blank App (Windows Phone)

2 right-click on the newly created project > Manage NuGet Packages... and add the Xamarin.Forms package.

3 right-click on project > Add > Reference and create a project reference to the shared Xamarin.Forms application project.

4 Edit App.xaml.cs to include the Init() method call, in the OnLaunched method around line 67:

```
// add this line
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (e); // requires LaunchActivatedEventArgs
// above this existing line
if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated) {}
```

5 . Edit MainPage.xaml - change the root element

```
<forms:WindowsPhonePage
...
   xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT"
...
</forms:WindowsPhonePage>
```

6 . Edit MainPage.xaml.cs to remove the : PhonePage inheritance specifier for the class name.

public sealed partial class MainPage  // REMOVE ": PhonePage"

7 . Still in MainPage.xaml.cs, add the LoadApplication call in the MainPage constructor (around line 28) to start your Xamarin.Forms app:

```
// below this existing line
this.InitializeComponent();
// add this line
LoadApplication(new YOUR_NAMESPACE.App());
```

8 . Double-click Package.appxmanifest to set these capabilities that are often required:

Internet (Client & Server)

9 . Finally, add any local resources (eg. image files) from the existing platform projects that are required.